# how to grep For a particular number in a csv file

Tags: linux, perl

I have this csv file

```
4,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
5,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0
6,1,0,1,3,1,0,0,0
7,1,0,1,4,1,0,0,0
8,1,0,2,3,2,0,0,0
9,1,0,2,4,2,0,0,0
10,1,0,2,5,2,0,0,0
11,1,0,2,6,2,0,0,0
12,1,1,3,3,3,0,0,1
13,1,1,3,4,3,0,0,1
14,1,1,3,5,3,0,0,1
15,1,1,3,6,3,0,0,1
16,1,1,3,7,3,0,0,1
17,1,1,4,6,4,0,0,1
18,1,1,4,7,4,0,0,1
19,1,1,4,8,4,0,0,1
20,1,1,5,7,5,0,0,1
```

I want to grep for line beginning with 8
i am trying

```
grep 8 example.csv
```

Then i get the foll o/p

```
8,1,0,2,3,2,0,0,0
18,1,1,4,7,4,0,0,1
19,1,1,4,8,4,0,0,1
```

I just want the line beginning with 8. how should i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep ^8, example.txt`

Where ^ indicates that the matching pattern must start at the beginning of the line. I've also added "," to the regular expression so it won't match lines starting with 80

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this with `perl`, I assume you're looking for a Perl solution. The simplest, but least robust would be:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /^8,/' example.csv
8,1,0,2,3,2,0,0,0
```

This does the same as @Dienow's `grep` solution. It's also possible to use the [`-F` command-line option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-F*_pattern_) to split the lines on commas - but note that this doesn't handle the case of quoted fields, escaped delimiters, etc.

```
$ perl -F, -nle 'print if $F[0]==8' example.csv
8,1,0,2,3,2,0,0,0
```

If you're working with CSV files a lot, I recommend you make use of [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) (also install [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) for speed).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary=>1, auto_diag=>2, eol=>$/ });
while ( my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV) ) {
    $csv->print(select, $row) if $row->[0] == 8;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag;
```

And then run this like so:

```
$ perl csv.pl example.csv
8,1,0,2,3,2,0,0,0
```

The only minor caveat being that it may reformat the input line (but it will of course still be proper CSV).

Comment: I'd typically only break out `Text::CSV` if I know I have multiline/quoted fields. Otherwise `split` does the job, and that's both simple and covers a usefully large proportion of cases.

Comment: @Sobrique If I knew *for sure* that the format was simple, I agree with you - although in my experience requirements tend to grow unexpectedly . In this case, if I were coding defensively, I'd probably write `/^\d(?:,\d)*$/ or die "invalid format";` to play it safe before `split`ting.